# I need help with this geocaching puzzle

Tags: geocaching

There is a geocaching puzzle that hasn’t never been solved. It has a video that I will link below. Basically from the video you have to get a set of coordinates. There is a checker below that will say if you are correct. The Coords have to be in the
N 43 13.XXX W 079 49.XXX format... please help me.

Video  https://youtu.be/4W1Zg2YljIQ

Checker http://geocheck.org/geo_inputchkcoord.php?gid=62005178cda477b-9885-405d-8593-a4ffe86cb00a

Keep in mind the name of the puzzle is written backwards... so that could have something to do with it

Comment: Google does not recognize this notation when xxx are replaced with 000. may be this could help?

Comment: try to reverse the video and hear what they say